# (Cordova/Ionic) Play/loop sound using notification volume

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

so I wondered if anyone knows of a way to achieve something I thought would be an easy plugin to find but turns out not to be.

I'm working on a project in Ionic/Cordova for Android & iOS and want to be able to play/loop a custom sound to the user when they receive an incoming request, however as it's a sound for a 'notification' I would like it to use the 'notification/ringer' volume and not the 'Media' volume.

I got a sound playing using 'cordova-plugin-nativeaudio' but this does use the 'Media' volume, which again doesn't make sense in the context.

I've spent the day Googling but haven't come up with anything. Can anyone recommend anything that could work? Thanks.